# DT Ramp Signal Summation Notation Help?

Tags: dsp, math, math-notation

[image: Question]

I cannot understand how the summation range has changed via substitution of m.

**EDIT:**

Full problem with solution (for context):

[image: Original Problem]

Comment: The Photon, Why am I substituting k for m when m=n-k and not m=k? And how does n become the new upper limit? Explain a bit more.

Comment: You're making the substitution m=n-k, and summing over some values of m. But you want to sum the same terms you had before. So, when k=0, what does m equal? That's one of your limits when summing over m. And when k = infinity, what does m equal? That's your other limit in the new summation.

Comment: Okay. So the prime purpose of the substitution was to manipulate the summand by substituting with an "arbitrary" m in order to match one sampling equation involving delta which I have (which is in the same form of the bottom equation utilizing the m substitution), and the aftermath was the sum limits being changed, correct? The goal is changing the summand, not the limits (limit change is just the effect of changing the summand, which I should take into account for proper evaluation of the sum).

Comment: Probably, but you haven't included enough further steps in the calculation for me to tell.

Comment: Question is edited to include original context of my summation question.

Comment: Sorry, reading sidways gives  me a headache.

Comment: Check now. By the way, can you also explain the summation boundary changes at the end of the problem? In the last line of calculation, how did the unit step functions get cancelled to 1, and why did that affect the summation boundary (m=-inf & m=n changed to a sum of m=0 & m=n and m=1 & m=n)?

Comment: They just used \$\sum_{n=0}^m a_n = a_0 + \sum_{n=1}^m a_n\$. If you're not comfortable with it, start by writing out the first few terms of each summation, then rearranging things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you substituted m = n-k, that also swaps the limits.

Because when \$k=\infty\$ (the old upper limit), \$n-k=-\infty\$. Since that is lower than any other index in the summation, it becomes the new lower limit.

**Edit**

I think the problem you were given is itself a bit wrongheaded since you can just pull out the first term of the first summation and get

$$\begin{align}
   \sum_{m=0}^n (n-m) - \sum_{m=1}^n(n-m) 
   &= (n-0) + \sum_{\color{red}{m=1}}^n (n-m) - \sum_{m=1}^n(n-m)\\
   &= n
\end{align}$$

No mucking about with delta functions is needed to get the desired result.